# indexOf in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays

Just wondering is there the same method for an Array object similar to indexOf in JavaScript?

For example:

```
arr = %w{'a', 'b', 'c'}
c = 'c'
if (arr.indexOf(c) != -1)
// do some stuff
else
// don't do some stuff
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is the `.index` method of Array.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-index

In ruby, only `false` and `nil` are considered as false value, so you could just do:

```
arr = %w{a, b, c}
c = 'c'
if arr.index c
  # do something
else 
  # do something else
end
```

Comment: Edit your answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617036/ruby-why-arr-wa-b-c-a-b-c/12617106#12617106), and will get a point for the correct answer

Comment: @DanMyasnikov I just used the `arr` from you question, yes `'c'` is not in your array, `"'c'"` does.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check the presence of an element in the array, you can use [`include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
if arr.include?(c)
  # do stuff
else 
  # don’t
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Array#index for this:

```
c = 'c'
%w{a b c}.index(c)
```

Comment: I think you meant to write `%w{a b c}`

Comment: @waldrumpus Yes, thanks, copypasted from source in the question.

Comment: So you did - sorry, I should have posted the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

```
if arr.last == c
  # do some stuff
else
  # don't do some stuff
end
```