# Ruby. Why arr = %w{'a', 'b', 'c'} => ["'a',", "'b',", "'c'"]

Tags: ruby, arrays

Coming from this question [indexOf in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616878/indexof-in-ruby),

Wondering why in Ruby 
`arr = %w{'a', 'b', 'c'} #=> ["'a',", "'b',", "'c'"]`

Answer (score 2):

`%w` initializes array separating contents in brackets (or other symbols) by space (if you need space escape it with `\`).

Answer (score 2):

`%w{one two}` is a shortcut for `["one", "two"]`: the `%w{...}` notation takes the **space-separated** elements as strings for the array.

This is actually the whole reason behind `%w{...}`: writing arrays without quotes or commas to separate the elements, thus allowing the use of quotes and commas without escaping them.

Comment: ... or in this case, writing arrays with data that contains quotes and commas (but no spaces) and not wanting to have to escape them.

Comment: @Thilo True. :)  Thanks for the feedback, I have now “adjusted” my answer.